# How to add circular mask on camera in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, camera, mask

Now I am swift newbie but I want to learn how to add circular mask on Camera in swift.
Now I am using Xcode7.2.1, swift 2.1, but I have no idea for that.
And I am developing this camera application by using the https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/CameraManager as third party library.
Here, I want to add my custom circular mask on Camera.
I am wondering who can help me to get this!
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController` has an **`cameraOverlayView`** property which you can use to provide a custom view that will act as an overlay. The example below creates an overlay view which is a square. Experiment with it to get what you want.

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {

    if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
        return
    }

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;

    //Create camera overlay
    let pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height, imagePicker.view.bounds.width, imagePicker.view.bounds.height - imagePicker.navigationBar.bounds.size.height - imagePicker.toolbar.bounds.size.height)
    let squareFrame = CGRectMake(pickerFrame.width/2 - 200/2, pickerFrame.height/2 - 200/2, 200, 200)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pickerFrame.size)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context))
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, squareFrame.origin.x, squareFrame.origin.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, squareFrame.origin.x + squareFrame.width, squareFrame.origin.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, squareFrame.origin.x + squareFrame.width, squareFrame.origin.y + squareFrame.size.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, squareFrame.origin.x, squareFrame.origin.y + squareFrame.size.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, squareFrame.origin.x, squareFrame.origin.y)
    CGContextEOClip(context)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pickerFrame.origin.x, pickerFrame.origin.y)
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    CGContextFillRect(context, pickerFrame)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)

    let overlayImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    let overlayView = UIImageView(frame: pickerFrame)
    overlayView.image = overlayImage
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Thank you. But, Do you have exerienced in CameraManager? If you have, I am happy to know how to add customized circular mask on the center of camera in swift 2.0. Thanks again.

Comment: How do I get the image in did finish image picker delegate. I cant able to get using "info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage"